# How can I animate two objects merging smoothly, similarly to metaballs?

Tags: animation, shaders, meta-objects

I want to achieve the effect of an object being smoothly swallowed by water - on contact the two objects should have a gradual transition, instead of an ugly rough seam at their intersection. Something similar to how two metaballs merge, but ideally with more control and flexibility.

The objects are pretty abstract, so no need to handle complex geometry, but directly using metaballs is also too restricting. What are my best other options?